# Problems configuring Cmake via macports

Tags: cmake, macports, inkscape

I get the following error message when trying to install inkscape via Macports:

```
$ sudo port install inkscape

--->  Computing dependencies for cmake 
--->  Configuring cmake 
Error: Failed to configure cmake: configure failure: command execution failed Error: See /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_devel_cmake/cmake/main.log for details. 
Error: Unable to execute port: upgrade cmake failed Christian-Tofts-MacBook-Pro:~ clta$
```

Im running High Sierra OS and port version 2.5.4

Any input on how to fix this?

Comment: Have you checked the file `/opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_devel_cmake/cmake/main.log` noted in the error message?

Comment: Have you asked at https://github.com/macports/macports-ports, too? That would be the correct address if you want anything fixed for everyone, not just for yourself.